# Using Slave database as primary while Master gets updated?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have a problem where the performance of my database is impacted by several million lines of updates that run (it takes more or less 3 days, so we usually run them over a weekend)

However since the site is live, search performance is impacted. A 3 second query to pull 1.3 million records and page through them takes in excess of the timeout values by default in sql server sometimes. This obviously creates a user experience no one wants (or can afford to) to have happen.

My question now. If I setup replication on the Master to a Slave on the same server; Would I be able to point the website to the Slave and avoid that performance impact? Or would it just be duplicating the same problem since the Master will push any updates through to the Slave in any case?

Comment: Paging through 1.3 million rows and a 3 day update? Surely you'd want to fix things like this first...

Comment: The data needs to be ordered by publication date, so when paging is implemented it shows the newest books first and then goes chronologically backwards in time. The 3 day update used to take 37 days +- and it consists of 7 million records coming from XML files given to us by the publishers.

Comment: And all 7 million rows have changed? Is there no way for the publisher to separate it into files that represent data that has actually changed, and data that hasn't?

Comment: About 4 million of those changed, I use the most unique/latest update they give me. So if they send through 5 updates for the same thing, I choose the last one and use that. And no. Working with Ingram/Nielsen and those guys usually ensures you have little to no power as to how you receive the data. The issue at hand isn't the updates, I'm "okay" with it. It's access to the DB re: search that is bother me. A 3 second query timing out when you run it first thing in the morning doesn't really sit nice with the client...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think replication is going to help you here, it is only going to make things on the source system worse IMHO.

Is it possible you can make a static copy of the data for the users running queries while the updates are going on? For reporting solutions that don't need to be up-to-the-minute, I've done this in several cases using two schemas - one that holds the static versions of the tables for querying, and one where the work is being done; when the work is done, switch. I go into this methodology in a little more detail here: [What is the best way to refresh a rollup table under load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498142/what-is-the-best-way-to-refresh-a-rollup-table-under-load)

Perhaps another thought is to make your updates more efficient, such that they don't take 3 days? Do you only do this on long weekends?

Comment: It used to run 37 days, and according to me this is the fastest I'll ever get them. This is running through 7 million XML file updates which I first prepare in a program I wrote (that does it under an hour) and have to then "nurse" into the relational database.

There should be no user changing anything on the database while things are happening, and to me, it's quite static. They have another database holding any user/item cart data which doesn't affect the current "search/read only" db. But I suspect the updates hold the fulltext-index (and indexes) "ransom" and this is why I get timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Question is, what is nature of your site ?? Do users use it just to "Search" or it does CRUD operations ?? If it is just for "Search" and Report generation then I agree with @Aaron. You can have some database just for reporting purposes, you can even use Log Shipping to automatically update your reporting database at very brief interval.

Is it possible that user can change data at the same time while records are being updated by your update process ?? In that case, you will have to update your Primary Database using your update job, and then again update Primary database for changes made by users using Slave database.

Comment: It's just for search. Only the administrator will have (doesn't yet) the right to add/edit data, but not on this scale.

Comment: Then I would go with a not so old slave database on running on same or different server. I am afraid that other opetions like Log Shipping or Replication will also not work in your case because your will always be updating that slave database.

Comment: I think I'll try duplicating the entire database. One will be in production while the other gets updated. Then once that one is updated it gets switched into production and a copy of that will then be used for the new duplicate