# How to manipulate databases across many SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server

I currently have four different servers all with many databases on them. Each server has between 1-4 databases/tables that I need consolidated on a different server and mapped to the columns in a table on that server.

As an example, lets say it was a user database I am creating on server D. The `userId` is in a table in a DB in server A, the `userName` is on server B, the `dateUserStarted` is on server C  (I know this is a stupid setup, its just for example)

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, how can I do this? I was also hoping to run a SQL Server Agent script that updated this merge table.

I've looked into "linked servers" and cannot seem to get it working. Is there something else I should be using?

Comment: Replication is the keyword here.

Comment: What about linked servers isn't working?

Comment: While not sure what "cannot seem to get it working" means, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498142/what-is-the-best-way-to-refresh-a-rollup-table-under-load for a manual-but-less-maintenance version of replication. You put this procedure on each server, schedule it, and replace <expensive query> with a query from the source linked server. You can take just the tables / columns / rows you want, and you can avoid the requirement of a timestamp column on every table you want to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the frequency of reads, size of data, and bandwidth between servers, you might be able to get away with a remote join solution which is the easiest to maintain.

Create a db and view on server D that will join the three sources of data (userid, userName,dateUserStarted) from the other servers using Linked Servers.
For example, server d will have three linked server objects called serverA, serverB, and ServerC.

Your View will look something like this. (I make some assumptions about remote table primary key being "Id").

```
Create view vUserData
as
SELECT A.userId, B.userName,C.dateUserStarted FROM [serverA].[TheDataBaseName].[dbo].[TableWithUserId] A
   join [serverB].[TheDataBaseName].[dbo].[TableWithUserName] B on A.userId=B.id
   join [serverC].[TheDataBaseName].[dbo].[TableWithDateUserStarted] C on A.userId=C.id
```

Comment: After linking the servers with the GUI it worked, I must have been messing up the stored procedures. I'm doing your join solution, just not in a view.